# Unique sorting: Redirect output to the same file

Tags: command-line, bash

Is there any short way to save the pipe output to the same file that it's processed. For example, this is what I am actually doing

```
$ cat filename | sort | uniq > result
$ rm -f filename
$ mv result filename
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do it in just one line (not appending those commands using &&)

This is not the way, but to get an idea

```
$ cat filename | sort | uniq > filename
```

Comment: `echo $(cat filename | sort | uniq > result) > filename` or something ? Just passing by, I don't have time to try it.

Comment: @redraw: UUOC, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `sponge` from [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package:

```
LC_ALL=C sort -u filename | sponge filename
```

You also don't need pipe to `uniq`, since when `sort` has `-u` option to unique lines when sorting.

Note that on GNU system with UTF-8 locales, `sort -u` or `sort | uniq` didn't give you unique lines, but the first from sequence of lines which sort the same in current locale.

```
$ printf '%b\n' '\U2460' '\U2461' | LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 sort | LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 uniq
①
```

gave you only `①`. Changing locale to C force the sorting order based on the byte values:

```
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ printf '%b\n' '\U2460' '\U2461' | LC_ALL=C sort | LC_ALL=C uniq
①
②
```

Answer (score 15):

You don't need any extra command like `cat` and `uniq` and also without using `rm` command and `mv` command to removing and renaming the filename. just use simple command.

```
sort -u filename -o filename
```

```
 -u, --unique
        with -c, check for strict ordering; without -c, output only  the
        first of an equal run

 -o, --output=FILE
        write result to FILE instead of standard output
```

#### How it work?

`sort` command sorts your filename and with `-u` option, removes duplicate lines from it. then with `-o` option writes the output to the same file with in place method.

Comment: If system crash when `sort` is running, you will loose your original file.

Comment: thanks! in this example, with ´sort´ particularly, I should do that. However I was thinking about a general case. @Gnouc, haha there's no way to think that if it didn't happen to you, right?

Answer (score 3):

Your suggested example (below) doesn't work because you'd actually be reading from and writing to the same file simultaneously.

```
$ cat filename | sort | uniq > filename
```

The idea with a pipe or redirect is that the command on the left and right hand side of each pipe or redirect run simultaneously, in parallel.  The command on the right processes information as it is handed over to it from the command on the left, while the command on the left is still running.

In order for your scenario to work, the command that reads from the file would need to finish before the command that writes to the file begins.  In order for this to work you would need to redirect the output into a temporary location first, then once that's finished, send it from the temporary location back into the file.

A better way to do this is basically like in your former example, where you redirect to a temporary file then rename that file back to the original (except that you don't need to delete the file first, because moving deletes any existing target).

```
$ cat filename | sort | uniq > result
$ mv -f result filename
```

You could also save it into a string variable, except that only works when data is small enough to all fit in memory at once.

Comment: As someone put out in a suggested edit, you can change `cat filename | sort` to just `sort filename` - `cat` is unnecessary here.

Comment: My example below wasn't the way to do it. Thanks for clarification. `cat` could be unnecessary in this case but I was focusing on the redirection part.

Comment: I was explaining *why* your below example wouldn't work.  I know that you knew it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! In fact I didn't know what was really happening.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tee` command:

```
sort -u filename | tee filename > /dev/null
```

The `tee` command reads from standard input and writes to standard output *and* files.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: This does not work http://askubuntu.com/a/752451

Comment: This _does_ work for me.  e.g., to move a line to the bottom of a file: `(cat ~/file | grep -v 3662 ; printentry 3662) | tee ~/file > /dev/null` works.  Like the original post, this doesn't work if you just `> ~/file` without the `tee`.  Tee seems similar here to `sort -o file`, which writes to the named file without continuing the same pipe.

Comment: *Wait, sorry!*  I've seen empirically this will unpredictably lose data as explained in the link from @Steven.  Make a file with the numbers 1..9 on 9 lines.  The following will work several times, and then occasionally remove all of the data from the file: `(cat x | grep -v 7 ; echo 7) | tee x > /dev/null; cat x`  I recommend a temp file and `mv` or perhaps the solution from @Steven's link.

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg have you seen my answer on this page?

Comment: Yes, <| tee file> solution does not work for me as well. Better to use sort -o.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc 'sort u|x' filename
```

1. `sort u` sort unique
2. `x` write if changes have been made (they have) and quit