# Reading and writing a file: tee command

Tags: command-line, bash, tee

It is well known that a command like this:

```
cat filename | some_sed_command >filename
```

erases file filename, as the output redirection, being executed before the command, causes filename to be truncated.

One could solve the issue in the following way:

```
cat file | some_sed_command | tee file >/dev/null
```

but I'm not sure this would work in any case: what happens if file (and the result of the sed command) is very big? How can the operating system avoid to overwrite some content which is still not read? I see that there is also a sponge command which should work in any case: is it "safer" than tee?

Comment: What is your main goal ? ( in simple terms )

Comment: @Serg simply understand how things work... The answer written by kos clarifies the matter

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> One could solve the issue in the following way:

```
cat file | some_sed_command | tee file >/dev/null
```

**No**.

The chances `file` will be truncated drop, but there's no guarantee `cat file | some_sed_command | tee file >/dev/null` will not truncate `file`.

It all depends on which command is processed first, as opposed to what one may expect, [commands in a pipe are not processed left-to-right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37508/114435). There's no guarantee about which command will be picked first, so one might as well just think of it as randomly picked and *never* rely on the shell not picking the offending one.

Since the chances for the offending command to be picked first in between three commands are lower than the chances for the offending command to be picked first in between two commands, it's less likely that `file` will be truncated, but *it's still going to happen*.

`script.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do
    cat >file <<-EOF
    foo
    bar
    EOF
    cat file |
        sed 's/bar/baz/' |
        tee file >/dev/null
    [ -s file ] &&
        echo 'Not truncated' ||
        echo 'Truncated'
done |
    sort |
    uniq -c
rm file
```

```bsh
% bash script.sh
 93 Not truncated
  7 Truncated
% bash script.sh
 98 Not truncated
  2 Truncated
% bash script.sh
100 Not truncated
```

So *never* use something like `cat file | some_sed_command | tee file >/dev/null`. Use `sponge` as Oli suggested.

As an alternative, for thighter environments and / or relatively small files one may use a here string and a command substitution to read the file before any command is run:

```bsh
$ cat file
foo
bar
$ for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do <<<"$(<file)" sed 's/bar/baz/' >file; done
$ cat file
foo
baz
```

Answer (score 10):

For `sed` specifically, you can use its `-i` in-place argument. It just saves back to the file it opened, eg:

```
sed -i 's/ /-/g' filename
```

If you want to do something beefier, assuming you're doing more than `sed`, yes, you can buffer the whole thing with `sponge` (from the `moreutils` package) which will "soak up" all the stdin before writing out to the file. It's like `tee` but with less functionality. For basic usage though, it's pretty much a drop-in replacement:

```
cat file | some_sed_command | sponge file >/dev/null
```

Is that safer? Definitely. It probably has limits through so if you're doing something colossal (and can't in-place edit with sed), you might want to do your edits to a second file and then `mv` that file back to the original filename. That should be atomic (so anything depending on these files won't break if they need constant access).

Answer (score 1):

Oh, but `sponge` is not the only option; you do not have to obtain `moreutils` in order to get this to work properly.  Any mechanism will work as long as it satisfies the following two requirements:

1. It accepts the name of the output file as a parameter.
2. It only creates the output file once all input has been processed.

You see, the well known problem that the OP is referring to is that the shell will create all of the files that are necessary for the pipes to work before even beginning to execute the commands in the pipeline, so it is the shell that actually truncates the output file (which unfortunately is also the input file) before any of the commands have even had a chance to start executing.

The `tee` command does not work, even though it satisfies the first requirement, because it does not satisfy the second requirement: it will always create the output file immediately upon starting, so it is essentially as bad as creating a pipe straight into the output file.  (It is actually worse, because its use introduces a non-deterministic random delay before the output file gets truncated, so you might think that it works, while in fact it does not.)

So, all we need in order to solve this problem is some command that will buffer all of its input before producing any output, and that is capable of accepting the output filename as a parameter, so that we do not have to pipe its output into the output file.  One such command is `shuf`. So, the following will accomplish the same thing that `sponge` does:

```
    shuf --output=file --random-source=/dev/zero
```

The `--random-source=/dev/zero` part tricks `shuf` into doing its thing without  doing any shuffling at all, so it will buffer your input without altering it.

Comment: Clever! :-D Though sponge uses a temp file if it gets low on memory. Very rarely important, but nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%!some_sed_command' -cx filename
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `!` Run command
3. `x` Save and quit